# How to say "I think" if there is more than one sentence.

Tags: grammar

So usually when saying 'I think' you use 'と思います' but that is normally used with a single sentence like '美味しかったと思います。' But how do you say 'I think' when you have multiple sentences? For example I am trying to say.

> 'Is marriage or work more important for them?' If marriage is more important, they should get married. If work is more important, they should not get married and work, I think.'

I have got this so far (I know that it is very bad so I'm sorry about it, I haven't done many constructions like this before.)

> この人のために、結婚か仕事は一番大切ですか。結婚は一番大切なら、結婚します。仕事は一番大切なら、結婚をしませんしはたらきます。

(I'm sorry I know this paragraph is a grammatical mess.) I am answering a question so I would like to add 'I think' so it doesn't sound like I am saying she should do this for certain.

Answer (score 2):

> how do you say 'I think' when you have multiple sentences?

I think you could say 「～～て形、～～終止形 + べきだ + と思う」, as in...

> その人にとって、結婚と仕事のどちらが（より）大切ですか。
>   結婚が（より）大切なら結婚**して**、仕事が（より）大切なら結婚｛しないで/せずに｝働くべき**だと思い**ます。

You could also use [大事]{だいじ} or [重要]{じゅうよう} instead of 大切.

or...

> その人にとって、結婚と仕事のどちら（の[方]{ほう}）が大事ですか。
>   結婚（の方）が大事なら結婚**して**、仕事（の方）が大事なら結婚｛しないで/せずに｝働くべき**だと思い**ます。

Comment: 結婚も仕事も両方・・・ってのはダメなのかぁ～～

Answer (score 1):

You would still use 思う in this case. Your translation has some problem though. First, you can't use ために like that, here I would use には. Second, you should use その.

> その人には、結婚と仕事のどちらが一番重要なことですか。

You don't need to repeat 一番大切 in the following part of your sentence.

> 結婚なら結婚するべきで、仕事なら一生独身にして働くべきだということを、私は思う。

I can't vouch that my phrases are perfectly natural but I can tell you for sure that in this case too, you would use nothing more than 思う but you should glue your sentence together.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just wasn't sure how to incorporate the 思う.

Comment: @FoolishStrawberry If this answer helped then you might consider upvoting it :)

Comment: I have but I have under 15 rep so the public score doesn't change unfortunately.